# fullcalendar backgroundColor property

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to add a background color to an event but with no luck.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', { id: 1, title: 'hello', start: selected_date, allDay: true, color: '#FF0000', backgroundColor: '#000000' }, false);
```

Any idea why this won't work? The border color seems to work but not the backgroundColor

Comment: See in documentation event object properties [classname].

Comment: tried that but no luck with the class names, the background doesn't want to change color

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add both the stylesheets then the backgroundColor will not work.

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css")" />
```

After removing the fullcalendar.print.css then the backgroundColor decided to render correctly.

Comment: Nice! Never would have figured that out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add the media attribute

```
    <link href="../css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link media='print' href="../css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

I was setting it up in my bundle config in asp but that didn't add the media property so it was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The background color for events is defined in the fullcalendar.css file under the section

```
/* Global Event Styles
```

(Line 261, in version 2.0 beta)

You can access it programmatically like this:

```
$('.fc-event').css('background-color','#3a87ad');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it stick (change false parameter to true, at the end), probably a new event is overlapping and make it change properties.
"Normally, the event will disappear once the calendar refetches its event sources (example: when prev/next is clicked). However, specifying stick as true will cause the event to be permanently fixed to the calendar.", from Documentation, http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it: I placed backgroundColor in the chart event:

```
chart: { 
    type: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
},
```

Answer (score -3):

try this may be it works for you.

```
 background: '#eeeef0
```

Do not write backgroundColor.

Comment: still no luck, the documentation says to use backgroundColor so background shouldn't and doesn't work